# Search Function does not work on the search result page Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

After searching, it goes to the result page. In my case:

```
Route::post('/search', 'Frontend\FrontController@filterSearch');
```

In that page, there is the same search form as in every other page. Every other page search filtering works fine with no issues. But when I try to search from the result page (after searching something), I have to select all the fields in order for the search to filter the result. In other pages, I do not have to select all the fields. Here is my controller:

```
public function filterSearch(Request $request){

//imports
$categories = Category::all();
$languages = Language::all();
$years = Year::all();

//partials menu variable
$menu = Menu::all();

$movie = Movie::query();

// Search for a movie based on its name.
if ($request->name != null) {
    $movie->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%');
}

// Search for a movie based on the year.
if ($request->year != null) {
    $movie->where('year_id', '=', $request->year);
}

// Search for a movie based on the language.
if ($request->language != null) {
    $movie->where('language_id', '=', $request->language );
}

// Search for a movie based on the review.
if ($request->review != null) {
    $movie->where('review', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->review . '%');
}

// Get the results and return them.
$filtered = $movie->latest()->paginate(20);

//return $request->language;
return view('frontend/search/filter-search', compact('filtered', 'menu', 'categories', 'languages', 'years'));


}
```

Here is the form (which is the same for every other page):

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'Frontend\FrontController@filterSearch', 'class' => 'form-style-1']) !!}                            

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
      <label>Enter Name</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 form-it">
       <label>Language</label>
       <div class="group-ip">
       <select name="language" class="ui fluid dropdown">
          <option>Filter Language</option>
             @foreach($languages as $language)
          <option value="{{$language->id}}">{{ucfirst($language->language)}} 
          </option>
             @endforeach
      </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 form-it">
      <label>Enter Reviews (In stars e.g 7.5)</label>
      <input name="review" type="text" placeholder="Enter Reviews Amount">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 form-it">
     <label>Release Year</label>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
         <select name="year">
             <option>Year</option>
                  @foreach($years as $year)
             <option value="{{$year->id}}">{{$year->year}}</option>
                  @endforeach
        </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 ">
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here, if I search using the name 'the' and only the year while leaving the language blank, the search works as intended. But on the results page, if I do the same, it gives me no results unless I have all the fields filled. Including the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. The problem was that on my search result page, I had some fields which were not returning null. I used `dd($request->all())` to see if everything was returning null. But some fields did not return null and that was the issue. I forgot to put `value=“”` on the first option.